# MySQL: How to sum all row values from the returned output and print the total at the last

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum the row values from the my pre-written query and print them as total in a separate row at last, used rollup but not getting the desired output. Can anyone please help me out on how to achieve the condition in MySQL.?

Query:

```
SELECT client, 
       flag, 
       start_hour, 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='8', count, NULL))  AS '8h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='9', count, NULL))  AS '9h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='10', count, NULL)) AS '10h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='11', count, NULL)) AS '11h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='16', count, NULL)) AS '16h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='17', count, NULL)) AS '17h' 
FROM   (SELECT client, 
               Sum(count)                                   count, 
               start_hour, 
               flag, 
               IF(deploy_time = 0, start_hour, deploy_time) deploy_time 
        FROM   sample 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  3, 
                  4, 
                  5) tb1 
GROUP  BY client, 
          flag, 
          start_hour 
ORDER  BY 1, 
          3;
```

Query Output: Attached the screenshot FYI

[image: Output from my query]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired output expecting]

Answer (score 0):

Try Rollup with grouping

```
SELECT client, 
       flag, 
       start_hour, 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='8', count, NULL))  AS '8h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='9', count, NULL))  AS '9h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='10', count, NULL)) AS '10h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='11', count, NULL)) AS '11h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='16', count, NULL)) AS '16h', 
       Group_concat(IF(deploy_time='17', count, NULL)) AS '17h' 
FROM   (SELECT client, 
               Sum(count)                                   count, 
               start_hour, 
               flag, 
               IF(deploy_time = 0, start_hour, deploy_time) deploy_time 
        FROM   sample 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  3, 
                  4, 
                  5) tb1 
GROUP  BY client, 
          flag, 
          start_hour 
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING grouping(client) = 1 and grouping(flag) = 1 and grouping(Starg_hour) =1
ORDER  BY 1, 
          3;
```

[Reference for grouping](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: I didn't thing grouping was available in mysql do you have a reference for it?